# Slurmd fails to start with the following error: fatal: Unable to determine this slurmd's NodeName

Tags: slurm

I'm trying to setup slurm on a bunch of aws instances, but whenever I try to start the head node it gives me the following error:

fatal: Unable to determine this slurmd's NodeName

I've setup the instances /etc/hosts so they can address each other  as node1-6, with node6 being the the head node. This the hosts file for node6 all other nodes have a similar hosts file.

/etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost node6

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts

<Node1 IP> node1
<Node2 IP> node2
<Node3 IP> node3
<Node4 IP> node4
<Node5 IP> node5
```

/etc/slurm-llnl/slurm.conf:

```
###############################################################################
#                 Sample configuration file for SLURM 2
###############################################################################
#
# This file holds the system-wide SLURM configuration. It is read
# by SLURM clients, daemons, and the SLURM API to determine where
# and how to contact the SLURM controller, what other nodes reside
# in the current cluster, and various other configuration information.
#
# SLURM configuration parameters take the form Keyword=Value, where
# at this time, no spacing is allowed to surround the equals (=) sign.
# Many of the config values are not mandatory, and so may be left
# out of the config file. We will attempt to list the default
# values for those parameters in this file.
#
# This simple configuration provides a control machine named "laptop"
# to run the Slurm's central management daemon and a single node
# named "server" which execute jobs. Both machine should have Slurm
# installed and use this configuration file. If you have a similar
# configuration just change the values of ControlMachine, for the
# control machine and PartitionName and NodeName for job execution
#
###############################################################################
#

ControlMachine=node6
#ControlAddr=
#BackupController=
#BackupAddr=
#
AuthType=auth/munge
CacheGroups=0
#CheckpointType=checkpoint/none
CryptoType=crypto/munge
#DisableRootJobs=NO
#EnforcePartLimits=NO
#Epilog=
#PrologSlurmctld=
#FirstJobId=1
JobCheckpointDir=/var/lib/slurm-llnl/checkpoint
#JobCredentialPrivateKey=
#JobCredentialPublicCertificate=
#JobFileAppend=0
#JobRequeue=1
#KillOnBadExit=0
#Licenses=foo*4,bar
#MailProg=/usr/bin/mail
#MaxJobCount=5000
MpiDefault=none
#MpiParams=ports:#-#
#PluginDir=
#PlugStackConfig=
#PrivateData=jobs
ProctrackType=proctrack/pgid
#Prolog=
#PrologSlurmctld=
#PropagatePrioProcess=0
#PropagateResourceLimits=
#PropagateResourceLimitsExcept=
ReturnToService=1
#SallocDefaultCommand=
SelectType=select/cons_res
SelectTypeParameters=CR_Core
SlurmctldPidFile=/var/run/slurm-llnl/slurmctld.pid
SlurmctldPort=6817
SlurmdPidFile=/var/run/slurm-llnl/slurmd.pid
SlurmdPort=6818
SlurmdSpoolDir=/var/lib/slurm-llnl/slurmd
SlurmUser=slurm
#SrunEpilog=
#SrunProlog=
StateSaveLocation=/var/lib/slurm-llnl/slurmctld
SwitchType=switch/none
#TaskEpilog=
TaskPlugin=task/none
#TaskPluginParam=
#TaskProlog=
#TopologyPlugin=topology/tree
#TmpFs=/tmp
#TrackWCKey=no
#TreeWidth=
#UnkillableStepProgram=
#UnkillableStepTimeout=
#UsePAM=0
#
#
# TIMERS
#BatchStartTimeout=10
#CompleteWait=0
#EpilogMsgTime=2000
#GetEnvTimeout=2
#HealthCheckInterval=0
#HealthCheckProgram=
InactiveLimit=0
KillWait=30
#MessageTimeout=10
#ResvOverRun=0
MinJobAge=300
#OverTimeLimit=0
SlurmctldTimeout=300
SlurmdTimeout=300
#UnkillableStepProgram=
#UnkillableStepTimeout=60
Waittime=0
#
#
# SCHEDULING
#DefMemPerCPU=0
FastSchedule=1
#MaxMemPerCPU=0
#SchedulerRootFilter=1
#SchedulerTimeSlice=30
SchedulerType=sched/backfill
SchedulerPort=7321
#SelectType=select/linear
#SelectTypeParameters=
#
#
# JOB PRIORITY
#PriorityType=priority/basic
#PriorityDecayHalfLife=
#PriorityFavorSmall=
#PriorityMaxAge=
#PriorityUsageResetPeriod=
#PriorityWeightAge=
#PriorityWeightFairshare=
#PriorityWeightJobSize=
#PriorityWeightPartition=
#PriorityWeightQOS=
#
#
# LOGGING AND ACCOUNTING
#AccountingStorageEnforce=0
#AccountingStorageHost=
#AccountingStorageLoc=
#AccountingStoragePass=
#AccountingStoragePort=
AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/none
#AccountingStorageUser=
ClusterName=cluster
#DebugFlags=
#JobCompHost=
#JobCompLoc=
#JobCompPass=
#JobCompPort=
JobCompType=jobcomp/none
#JobCompUser=
JobAcctGatherFrequency=30
JobAcctGatherType=jobacct_gather/none
SlurmctldDebug=3
SlurmctldLogFile=/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmctld.log
SlurmdDebug=3
SlurmdLogFile=/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmd.log
#
#
# POWER SAVE SUPPORT FOR IDLE NODES (optional)
#SuspendProgram=
#ResumeProgram=
#SuspendTimeout=
#ResumeTimeout=
#ResumeRate=
#SuspendExcNodes=
#SuspendExcParts=
#SuspendRate=
#SuspendTime=
#
#
# COMPUTE NODES


NodeName=node1 Procs=1 State=UNKNOWN
NodeName=node2 Procs=1 State=UNKNOWN
NodeName=node3 Procs=1 State=UNKNOWN
NodeName=node4 Procs=1 State=UNKNOWN
NodeName=node5 Procs=1 State=UNKNOWN
NodeName=node6 Procs=1 State=UNKNOWN



#PartitionName=debug Nodes=server Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
PartitionName=mycluster Nodes=node[1-6] Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
```

Comment: Try to add <Node6 IP> node6 in the hostfile. All the hostfiles should have the ip and hostnames of all the nodes including itself. Also, in the login node, try to check whether ssh is possible between all the nodes using nodename.

Comment: I tried adding <node6 ip> node6 into  /etc/hosts and it didn't work. all hostfiles have the ip and hostnames of all the nodes including itself. From the head node (node6) I can ssh into all other nodes.

Comment: What is the output of `hostname -s` on any of the node?

Comment: @damienfrancois so it was the hostname I edited the wrong files. I needed to change the `etc/hostname`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your

> ControlMachine=node6

replace node6 with the result of "hostname -s". Also specify ip as in "ifconfig"

```
ControlAddr=<your local ip>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem could be with the munge.key . So copy the /etc/munge/munge.key from master to compute node6 and restart the munge service.